# Required not working in ng selectize in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Espire theme. Even when I use NgNativeValidate required is not working in Ng-selectize when I submit.

My code:

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
       <label>Farm Manager<span style="color:red">&nbsp;*</span></label>
       
       <ng-selectize [config]="userSelectConfig" 
        [options] = "userSelectOptions"
        placeholder="Select Farm Manager" required
        [(ngModel)]="farm.farm_resp.id" name="user">       
       </ng-selectize>

      </div>
 </div>
```

Note: I haven't used the normal select tag because it doesn't provide Search options.

Comment: `ngModel` is not supported by `ng-selectize` instead use [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) See [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Thank you satpal. Actually i dont have any problem's with data binding. I am using required attribute, so when i submit to save. it should show ."Field is required" but now it is not showing.?